# fadeOut() method won't work with event.preventdefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

When my form is submitted and validated, I want my dialog to fadeout and close, I do not want the page to automatically refresh. If I use preventdefault the page doesn't refresh, but the dialog doesn't close either. What else do I need to do?

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
          number : {
            required: true
        }                                        
    },
    messages: {
        number : {
            required: "enter a phone number"                   
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form,event) {

        event.preventDefault();

    //this prevents a double click on the form button

    $("form :input:submit").click(function() {

             this.disabled = 'disabled';

    });

     //Here I want the dialog to slowly fade, then close, *then* reload the page. 
     //but it won't fade or close when I'm using preventDefault(). 

    $('#dialog').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          location.reload();
        });


    }  //closes submit handler  
});//close validate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `submitHandler` receive only 1 argument `form`, therefore trying to call  `event.preventDefault();` will cause exception and stop the below script from executing.

> The callback gets passed one argument:
>
> form
>
> Type: Element The form currently being validated, as a
>   DOMElement.

From [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Try `return false;` at the end of the function.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    $("form :input:submit").click(function() {

             this.disabled = 'disabled';

    });

    $('#dialog').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          location.reload();
        });

    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put `event.preventDefault();` at the end of your `submithandler` function.